# is a secured web service; Tester feature is not supported for secured services

Tags: java, web-services, security, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am new to JAVA and developing web service on NetBeans IDE 7.1.1. When I deploy or run service and try to test it from its tester link it says

> CalculateInventoryService is a secured web service; Tester feature is
>   not supported for secured services

I want to test the service. I googled but could not find solution.

please help that how could I test it from tester page.

Comment: Java is a word and not an acronym.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Projects View, right-click the Web Application -> Web Services -> WebServiceNode

and

select "Edit Web Service Attributes" from list

UnCheck **Secure Service** checkBox

Click O.k and Deploy it again

It Should work.